# Android device does not connect to firebase DebugView

Tags: android, firebase, debugview

I'm trying to connect the device to DebugView. but, do not connected.

I referenced the [DebugView document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=ko&utm_id=ad).

All I know is what is stated in this document.

Is there any other reason not to connect?

I simulated the following.

1. Open the terminal. and entered a command.
2. `adb devices`
3. `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.myapp`
4. start the app(com.example.myapp).
5. Check [[Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) -> Analytics -> DebugVIew]

If my question is not clear, talk to me please.

Comment: Note that the time setting of the device is normal.

Comment: And firebase's DebugView says there are no connected devices.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has the same symptoms as me.

Comment: Is anyone running DebugView now?

Comment: Not working for me neither... I'm happy to see that I am not alone. It drove me crazy :-)

Comment: It seems that Google does't know there is a service outage -> https://status.firebase.google.com/. Do not hesitate to contact their support to notify them there is a problem.

Comment: I'm happy too. I have reported to Firebase support team. And I think that problem needs time.

Comment: They just solved the problem. Should work now.

Comment: good. I have received e-mail. but, 'adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.' not working... Is it just me?

Comment: Terminal logs show that data has been uploaded, but doesn't reflect on DebugView for Android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with Firebase DebugView. It doesn't work on me either.

Answer (score 5):

I tried following steps and its working for me

1. Run your app in debug mode
2. Goto **Developer Options** -> **Select debug app** -> Select

You will see your device listed in **Firebase DebugView**

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your device and Laptop (While Making Connections with Firebase i.e. hitting command in CMD) is on same connection.
I am facing this issue, as VPN is connected in my device, but not on laptop.
When I connect VPN on laptop also. Device gets connected to Firebase debug view.

### **Steps to connect device**

1. Connect your device with laptop. Make sure your device Developer options should enable. And USB debugging on.
2. Open CMD. Hit "adb devices". A list of devices will come
   If you get adb is not internal and external command.
   Then First Go to adb

   - **How to Go to adb**

     - Check path of SDK manager in your computer. (You can check it from android Studio=> Tools => SDK manager => Copy Path)
     - Lets say path is C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
     - Go to this path on CMD
     - Then write cd platform-tools
     - Now write adb, it will work fine
3. adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [your_app_package_name]

> **What will be your app package name**

- If you are not using any build variant
  Copy package name from manifest file. Under application tag
- If you are using build variant
  Copy applicationId from your build.gradle file
  Lets say:
  Your applicationId is: com.abc.myApp
  And you are using two build variant

  - develop
  - production

### Then command will be:

```
For develop build variant:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.abc.myApp.develop
For production build variant:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.abc.myApp.production
```

---